# Convert JSON structure to proto-buf structure

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto3

My requirement is to share the data JSON to proto-buf.
I have JSON data. How to write a schema genric for handling all types of value.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "bool": true
    },
    {
      "string": "abc"
    },
    {
      "int": 22
    },
    {
      "json_object" : {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "example@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "json_array" : [
          {
            "name":"xyz"
          },
          {
            "age":2
          }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If, I am using `Map<string, string>` map. It's supported string value only.
If, I am using `Map<string, google.protobuf.Value>` map. The Value is not supported by `JSON` and `JSONArray`.

How do I handle all types in a single schema?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you're asking how to support arbitrary JSON using Protocol Buffers.

Because Protocol Buffers require a schema, the easiest way to represent generic|arbitrary|schemaless types using Protocol Buffers is to encapsulate the arbitrary type using a type that supports arbitrary content, i.e. using Protocol Buffers `string` or `bytes` types.

> **NOTE** `string` and `bytes` are restricted to 2^32 bytes

If your JSON content is a manageable (few) subset of possible types, you may want to consider representing each possibility as a distinct Protocol Buffer Message.

If your JSON content is many possible types but enumerable (you can name them), you  may want to consider [`Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any).